# Python3 textcoding issue: extra first character when reading from text file using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, encoding, text-files, string-length

I'm trying to read a number of ticker symbols from a text file, but seem to have a textcoding issue.

This is the contents of a test file 'tickers.txt':

```
SPG
WBA
```

This is my testcode:

```
    f = open("tickers.txt", 'r')
    for ticker in f:
        t = ticker.strip()
        if t:
          try:
            print(">"+t+"<" + ' length = '+ str(len(t)))
            i = 0
            while i < len(t):
              print(t[i])
              i += 1
            print('End')
          except ValueError:
            print('ValueError ticker')
```

And this is the resulting output:

```
>SPG< length = 4

S
P
G
End
>WBA< length = 3
W
B
A
End
```

For some reason there is an extra character in the first ticker symbol, which does not show when printed. Have read through several Q&A's here on StackOverflow I now assume it is a text coding issue, but don't understand yet how to solve this.... Do I need to add an 'encoding' statement to the file open command ? If so, which one ? How to detect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `print(t[i])` to `print(i, t[i], '{:04x}'.format(ord(t[i])))`, I can get the followin output indicating that the extra first character is [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

```
>﻿SPG< length = 4
0 ﻿ feff
1 S 0053
2 P 0050
3 G 0047
End
>WBA< length = 3
0 W 0057
1 B 0042
2 A 0041
End
```

Use `utf_8_sig` — [UTF-8 codec with BOM signature](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/codecs.html#module-encodings.utf_8_sig). On decoding, an optional UTF-8 encoded BOM at the start of the data will be skipped.

```
f = open("tickers.txt", mode='r', encoding='utf_8_sig')
```

instead of

```
f = open("tickers.txt", 'r')
```

BTW, do not forget `f.close()` …

Comment: Thanks JozefZ ! That seems to solve the problem, indeed. And yes, I should have added the f.close() - this code originated from a with ....as f: statement, which automatically closes the file. 
So I was right it was a textfile encoding issue... how to figure out which encoding to use ? Tried to find that before, but could not get a definite answer on that.